# Python Regex to match multiple headers and their paragraphs in multi line string

Tags: python, regex, multiline

I am trying to create a `Regular-Expression` in Python which should capture headers and text corresponding them in a multi-line string. Example string:

```
.Main Header
This is the main paragraph in the text. Also this is another sentence.
.Sub-Header
This is secondary header and text.
.Last Header
And this is the last header in the text.
```

Here `.Main Header`, `.Sub-Header` & `.Last Header` are the headers of paragraphs and next few lines (*text until next ".Header" string*) are the body of text. So my expected output is:

```
Header1 - .Main Header, Text1 - This is the main paragraph in the text. Also this is another sentence.
Header2 - .Sub-Header, Text2 - This is secondary header and text.
Header3 - .Last Header, Text3 - And this is the last header in the text.
```

I have tried to put together a `regex` to meet this expectation and it almost works, only challenge I am facing is to capture text where a `dot(.)` is in between a sentence (*for ex. Text1*), the stopping criteria for my `regex` is a `newline` and `dot(.)` as the next header begins from a `dot(.)`, so I am looking for help to differentiate a regular dot with a newline dot as my stopping criteria.

My current regex is:

```
^(.\w+[^\n]+)\n([^\.]+)
```

For `Text1` this captures:

```
This is the main paragraph in the text
```

But should capture:

```
This is the main paragraph in the text. Also this is another sentence.
```

Comment: Actually,there is no necessary to use `regex`.

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA - I know that, but I want to do it with regex and I am almost there.

Comment: Maybe they think you make it more complex?I don't know.

Comment: Maybe `^(.\w+[^\n]+)\n(.*?)\.$` which grabs all from the next line up until the last dot at the end of the line.  Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cPk723/1

Comment: @MDR - Thanks for help, I was missing this trick. You should add this as answer then I will mark this question as complete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe try the following regex...

```
^(.\w+[^\n]+)\n(.*?)\.$
```

...which grabs all characters from the second matched line up until the last dot at the end of the line.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/cPk723/1